# Sharepoint 2010 - Issues with calculated fields formula

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Strugling getting a simple formula working in a calculated field in Sharepoint 2010. I have the formula below:

```
=IF(([Column1]-[Column2])<0.33334,"OK","Not OK")
```

Basically I want this formula to return is yes or no the duration between the 2 dates is greater than 8 hours (in decimels it's 0.33334). This is the data the columns contains to give you an idea:

```
(text fields) Column1 = 2016-03-24 13:00
(text fields) Column2 = 2016-03-23 21:50
```

I keep getting a syntax error when trying to apply this formula.

Now if I do this formula:

```
([Column1]-[Column2])
```

This returns me with `0,631944444445253` (15 hours) as expected. But does anyone know why this isnt working?

Comment: Hello, a good advice is to 'write' those functions first in Excel as it is the same syntax (and functions available). It is easier to debug from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i commented, i always advice to do the same thing in Excel. It will be easier to debug.

I did this for you and in my language/culture settings, i had to change 0.33334 to 0,33334

As you write it returns 0,63194444.. i guess you will need to use the comma also instead of the dot separator...